# Different colors in ggplot when you upload a file vs. when you create a data of your own in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, read.csv

So, I have a dataset in .csv format, which is attached [here](https://ufile.io/5g26t), and I want to make the following graph in ggplot2.

```
df1 <- read.csv("obesity.csv")

ggplot(df1, aes(x = Levels, y = OR, color = col)) + 
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = UCI, ymin = LCI), width = 0.3) +  
  coord_flip() + 
  facet_grid(name ~ ., scales = "free_y", space = "free_y", switch = "y") + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1, size=1, col="brown") + 
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top") + 
  theme_bw() + 
  scale_color_manual(guide = FALSE, values =  c("red", "blue", "black", "green", "orange", 
"chocolate", "brown", "grey", "tomato", "navyblue", "purple1", "orchid4"))
```

As you can see the order of colors are completely different than what I chose. 
However, if I create the data in R by myself, then there is no problem.

```
df2 <- data.frame(
Levels = as.factor(c("Africa", "Europe", "Latin America", "Middle East", "High", 
"Upper middle", "Lower middle", "Secondary", "Post-Secondary", ">= 9 years", "Male", 
"> 60 min/day")), 
OR = c(0.72, 3.17, 0.51, 0.51, 0.38, 0.94, 1.04, 2.22, 3.49, 2.24, 1.9, 0.44), 
LCI = c(0.23, 0.68, 0.09, 0.2, 0.09, 0.29, 0.49, 0.72, 1.33, 1.14, 0.93, 0.19), 
UCI = c(2.28,9.5,2.92,1.32,1.62,3.07,2.22,6.77,9.16,4.39,3.87,1.03), 
name = as.factor(c("Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Income", "Income",
 "Income", "Education", "Education", "Age", "Sex", "PAL")), 
col = paste("col",1:12, sep=""))
```

Now, I am trying to understand what is the difference between the 2, and how can I set colors the same way as I want, when I am using a dataset in csv format.

Edit: I changed the variables in df2 to be factors, not characters.

Comment: When you read a file with `read.csv()` any columns with strings in are converted to factors. Your hand-made data frame is probably character. You can confirm this with `str(df1)`. If that's the case, load a csv with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` argument.

Comment: I checked it is still the same problem. No matter if stringsAsFactors = FALSE or TRUE, it is the same plot.

Comment: @Phi Also, I added as.factor to make sure that they are factors, not characters.

Comment: If `col1` through `col12` are supposed to be in the order they appear in the dataset in order to match the color vector you give, you'll need to set the levels of the `col` factor.  The default factor order will have, e.g., `col10` come before `col2`. An alternative for this example would be to put the actual color names in the dataset and use `scale_color_identity`.

Comment: @aosmith `scale_color_identity` corrects it. Thanks.